# Drupal render login form programmatically

Tags: forms, authentication, drupal-7

I'm trying to display the login form in a basic page.  When I'm logged in, this redirects me to the user account page.  When I'm logged out, this shows nothing.

```
<?php drupal_get_form("user_login"); ?>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Solved!

For D7:

```
<?php 
$elements = drupal_get_form("user_login"); 
$form = drupal_render($elements);
echo $form;
?>
```

For D6:

```
<?php 
echo drupal_get_form("user_login");
?>
```

Comment: To render the registration form, use `drupal_get_form('user_register_form')`